# How to access and authenticate a Google Apps Script doPost() Pub/Sub push endpoint properly?

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, google-cloud-pubsub

### Overall flow

I'm working with Google Cloud Platform (GCP), Google Apps Script (GAS), and the Pub/Sub service within a Google Workspace domain environment. This is the flow of requests/data, which works but clearly has auth issues:

1. GCP **Pub/Sub** service receives messages for a specific topic
2. Pub/Sub forwards the message to a **push endpoint** URL by POST
3. The push endpoint is a `doPost()` function within Google Apps Script (GAS), published as a **Web App**

### Details

I have enabled **authentication** for the **Service Account** used in the Pub/Sub delivery type options, i.e. Pub/Sub signs a JSON Web Token (JWT) and sends the JWT in the **authorization header** of the push request. *Edit:* The Service Account (Client ID) has a **domain-wide delegation** for the Scopes

- https://mail.google.com/
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

**Web App** deployments come with two options:

"Execute as"

- Me (name@workspace-domain.tld)
- User accessing the web app

"Who has access"

- Only myself
- Anyone within {workspace domain}
- Anyone with Google account
- Anyone

Right now, the web app executes as **Me** with **Anyone** having access. And it works.

### Problems

*<strike>The push endpoint is publicly accessible, but should not be. (1)</strike>*

**Follow-up:** "The push endpoint **must** be a publicly accessible HTTPS address" ([source](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push)) anyways, so "Who has access" will be set to "**Anyone**" by design.

Limiting the "Who has access" option to "anyone within {domain}" leads to unacknowledged messages inside the Pub/Sub subscription, `doPost()` will **not** run, but the endpoint returns straight `40X` HTTP codes (probably forbidden).

<strike>--> Question: How can I promote the Service Account to being seen as a user within the workspace domain, so it has access to the endpoint?</strike>

*The push endpoint should validate tokens sent by Pub/Sub. (2)*

In GAS, `doPost()` has no access to (authorization) headers sent to the web app endpoint URL (unfortunately and as far as I know). However, `ScriptApp.getIdentityToken()` gets an OpenID Connect identity token for the effective user, if the `openid` scope has been granted.

--> If problem (1) was solved, is it possible to authenticate and authorize the messages send to the endpoint within the GAS `doPost()` function using `ScriptApp.getIdentityToken()`? From my understanding, the Service Account should also become the `effective user`, i.e. "Execute as" = "User accessing the web app".

I might be missing something. So, thanks for any tips and advice!

### Doc links

Google Apps Script: Web Apps
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

GAS: ScriptApp.getIdentityToken()
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getidentitytoken

Using push subscriptions: Authentication and authorization by the push endpoint
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#authentication_and_authorization_by_the_push_endpoint

Comment: The jwt auth header needs drive scope.

Comment: Hi! Do you mean the scopes for the Google Workspace **domain-wide delegation** for the service account or is there another place where this scope would be necessary? Thanks.

Comment: Yes that. Also [edit] to provide exact error code and messages if any. @Tanaike's [documentation](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script/#error-messages) is the only thing that's fully documented

Comment: Thanks, I've added the Drive and Script scopes (see above). Pub/Sub does not provide any error logs for the unacknowledged message (?), I can only tell it's an HTTP code other than 102, 200, 201, 202, or 204. I guess I need to research a way to simulate/test Pub/Sub delivery!?

Comment: Then at least edit in the correct code.

Comment: The push endpoint must be a publicly accessible HTTPS address.But  push subscriptions can be configured to provide an authorization header to allow the endpoints to authenticate the requests or with app Engine Standard and Cloud Functions can use Automatic authentication. 
You can see more information in this link https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push

Comment: @RaulSaucedo Thanks for the clarification, I have edited my post.